# Do I need a transit visa in Dublin with change of terminals (Pakistani Citizen with Canadian PR card)?

Tags: transit, pakistani-citizens, dublin, canadian-residents

Do I need a transit visa in Dublin with change of terminals (Pakistani Citizen with Canadian PR card)

Comment: From what Terminal to what Terminal?

Comment: Where are you flying from?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold